# Can't open a new tab at my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm starting to learn about chrome extension, I had already created one, but when I try to open a new tab it open inside the extensions directory and not in a complete and clean new tab.
It opens **chrome-extension://ifaaiadijbjgfapbljbcifcjekajllnl/www.google.com** instead of just **www.google.com**

### **manifest.json:**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Open tab",
  "description": "Click to open google.com"
  "version": "1.0",
  "background" : {
    "scripts" : ["google.js"]
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon-16.png",
    "default_title": "Click to open google.com"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs"
  ],

  "icons":{ "16": "icon-16.png", "128": "icon-128.png" }
}
```

### **google.js:**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() { 
  chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) 
  {
    link = "www.google.com"
    chrome.tabs.create({url:link})
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Define Your var link as:

```
link = 'https://www.google.com'
```

Hope that will solve your problem. Good luck.